# react native firebase crashlytics in expo development build

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, crashlytics

I am using react native firebase crashlytics package.
I have already configured and installed the @react-native-firebase/app @react-native-firebase/auth modules successfully.
I am now trying to implement client side logs using the crashlytics log function, with no success.
I have followed the instructions in the official documentation site and added the @react-native-firebase/crashlytics to my expo plugins array. However, in the documentation they indicate that in order for it to work under a development build, a firebase.json config file must be provided, and so I did - but it seems that expo build completely ignores it.
I have tried several other methods as well (f.e providing the firebase.json configurations in the expo plugins array itself - again - did not work.)
attaching my app.json relevant fields and firebase.json file. I will appreciate any help, been stuck on it for days now.

app.json:

"expo": {
...,
"plugins": [
"@react-native-firebase/app",
"@react-native-firebase/auth",
"@react-native-firebase/crashlytics",
[
"expo-build-properties",
{
"ios": {
"useFrameworks": "static"
}
}
]
],
...
}

firebase.json (in the root folder of course):

{
"react-native": {
"crashlytics_debug_enabled": true,
"crashlytics_auto_collection_enabled": false
}
}

Tried to add firebase.json file, tried to add configurations like in the "expo-build-properties" described above - no success in development builds both on ios and android builds.